# detect when isEnabled localVideoTrack false WebRTC IOS

Tags: ios, webrtc

I using WebRTC to call video p2p. A call to B.

When A disable local video (use `localVideoTrack.isEnabled = false`) how to B detect A has disabled video and vice versa?

And when A minimize this video has disabled, how to detect it.

Comment: What do you use for signaling?

Comment: yes. i use signaling (WebRTC)

Comment: So you can use signaling channel to notify other user regarding changes at your side

Comment: Thanks you. But i don't understand why WeRTC don't support detect when remoteVideo has disabled :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see here 2 potential solutions:

1. Use WebRTC signaling channel (the same that you use for sdp and candidates exchange). This is an optimal solution here. So when you disable your camera then you simply send some signal message to your opponent about it, e.g:

   **{"videoEnabled": false}**
2. Use WebRTC stats reports. I'm not sure about this one, but probably it can work as needed. There are lots of stats keys, and I know there is set of stats data,  something like "**Receiver RTP statistics**", when you can track how many packets received, bytes received (*bytesReceived* and *packetsReceived*). When an opponent disabled video then this stats data will decrease. More useful info regarding stats is here https://testrtc.com/webrtc-internals-parameters/